# Remote EJB invocation fails for second time for stateful bean

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

I am writing a EJB code, with a stateful bean.

The HelloStatefulBean is packaged in a .EAR file and the EjbClient is packaged in .WAR file and both archives are deployed in JBOSS-EAP-6.2 server.
The EjbClient.java file gets called via REST-API(/test/execute)

I am calling the EJB from the EjbClient.java class. The call to the second method(sayHi()) from client to EJB fails, with "NoSuchEJBException", this behaviour seems a bit weird, as with the same context I was able to successfully call the first method(sayHello()).

Please let me know, what am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
Stateful bean:
    @Stateful(name = "helloejb")
    @StatefulTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 1)
    @TransactionManagement((TransactionManagementType.BEAN))
    public class HelloStatefulBean extends CloudProvider implements IHelloBean
    {
        public String sayHello(String name)
        {
            String str = "Hello " + name;
            System.out.println(str);
            ....
            ...
            ..
            .
            return str;
        }

        public void sayHi(String str)
        {
            System.out.println("Hi " + str);
            ....
            ...
            ..
            .
        }
    }

Remote Interface:
    @Remote
    public abstract interface IHelloBean
    {
        public abstract String sayHello(String paramString1);

        public abstract void sayHi(String paramString1);
    }

EJB Client:
    @Path("/test")
    public class EjbClient
    {
        @POST
        @Path("/execute")
        public Response execute()
        {
            String lookupName = "java:global/hello/hello/helloejb!com.test.beans.ifc.IHelloBean";
            Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
            LOGGER.info("Looking-up the EJB with name: " + lookupName);
            IHelloBean objRef = (IHelloBean)initialContext.lookup(lookupName);
            LOGGER.info("Lookup successful.");
            String msg = objRef.sayHello("XYZ");

            objRef.sayHi(msg);   // Fails on this method call with NoSuchEJBException
        }

    }
```

On firing the REST-API with URL:  `http://{JBOSS-SERVER-IP}:8080/api/test/execute`  , the REST-API gets called and the lookup for the EJB also is successful.
Further, the "sayHello()" method also gets successfully called, but on calling the "sayHi()" method from EjbClient, the application fails with exception:

```
 2014-11-22 20:02:26,724 +0530 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component helloejb for method com.test.beans.ifc.IHelloBean.sayHi(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: JBAS014300: Could not find EJB with id {[12, -41, -13,..., -121]}
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.java:63) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:249) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:58) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:83) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:42) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:125) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.sayHi(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.rest.server.EjbClient.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]

2014-11-22 20:02:26,744 +0530 ERROR [com.test.rest.server.EjbClient.execute] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS014300: Could not find EJB with id {[12, -41, -13,..., -121]}: javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: JBAS014300: Could not find EJB with id {[12, -41, -13,..., -121]}
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.java:63) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:249) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:58) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:83) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:42) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:125) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.25.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.25.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.sayHi(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.rest.server.EjbClient.execute(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) [jersey-servlet-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537) [jersey-servlet-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708) [jersey-servlet-1.11.jar:1.11]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:389) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
```

Comment: does sayHello() throws any exception?

Comment: @GabrielAramburu : No, sayHello() does not throw any exception. On further digging, I found that the exception occurs for sayHi() only, not for any other method. Cannot understand such weird behavior, i.e. invocation fails only a specific method.

Comment: try to remove the @StatefulTimeout annotation

Comment: @GabrielAramburu : Perfect!!! That was causing the problem, but I didn't remove the StatefulTimeout annotation(since it is a requirement for my assignment :) ), rather, I am performing EJB lookup before each method call from bean, so that the session timeout doesn't occur and the EJB is found on each instance.
Which of the following solutions is better:
1. Removing the StatefulTimeout annotation.
2. Or, doing EJB lookup before each EJB method call.

Do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If removing the `@StatefulTimeout` solves the `NoSuchEJBException` exception, and assuming that your are invoking the first and second method whitin the period of time the bean remains alive (1 minute), may be the Container has some problem regarding to this annotation . I did some research in google but I did not found any possible bug about this issue.

Regarding your comment, the answer is no, make a new lookup before invoke the second method is not a solution because you will get a different ejb reference, with a different state. It works because in your example you are not managing state, but under real  requirements you will need to keep the same ejb reference. (this is the reason for stateful)